# How to pass id in effects in angular ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx-effects

I am selecting a list and based on that I need to display selected list info.

Comment: you can pass a value in the constructor of `PortfolioEffects` Can you provide stackblitz?

Comment: where inside `getPortfolio()` method?

Comment: Okay, can you provide stackblitz where I can test or try?

Comment: Missing `getPortfolio()` method

Comment: So on basis of `U1` getting your data

Comment: Okay got it...give me minute will look

Comment: @Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hte4nq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am really not familiar with the ngrx just tried to subscribe to the observable and get the last object:

`View()` method:

```
constructor(private store: Store<IUserState>) {}

public user$: Observable<IUser[]>; -- declare once 

view(id) {
  this.store.dispatch(fromUserActions.loadUser({ id: id }));
  this.store.select(userQuery.getEntity).subscribe(value => {
    this.user$ = value[value.length - 1]; -- and assing the data as per values
    console.log(value[value.length - 1]);
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<pre *ngIf="userLoaded$">
    {{user$ | json}}
</pre>  -- Removed async pipe
```

**EDIT:**

```
view(id) {
    this.store.dispatch(fromUserActions.loadUser({ id: id }));
    this.store.select(userQuery.getEntity).subscribe(value => {
      this.user$ = new Observable<IUser>();
      this.user$ = value.filter(x=> x.id == id)[0];
      console.log(value.filter(x=> x.id == id)[0]);
    });
}
```

[`Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hte4nq)